# Finding Average of every column in 2D array

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to find average of all of the columns in a 2D array and store them into a 1D array. 
From that 1D array I want to return the lowest number's location. 
Here's my code, it does produce an answer (no compile/ run-time errors) however the answer it gives is not correct.

```
int function(){
    int m, n,p;
    for(m = 0; m < NROW; m++){//I think the problem must be within this set of for loops.
        for(n = 0; n < NCOL; n++){
            averages[n] += twoD[n][m]; //averages is an array of type double
        }
    }

    for(p = 0; p < NCOL; p++){
        averages[p] = (((double)averages[p])/((double)NROW));
    }

    int d, location;
    int lowest = averages[0];
    for ( d = 1 ; d < NCOL ; ++d )
        {
            if ( averages[d] < lowest )
            {
               lowest = averages[d];
               location = d;
            }
        }
return location;
}
```

Comment: Is your `averages` an array of ints?

Comment: averages is an array of doubles.

Comment: Did you initialize the averages array?

Comment: yes. I did it this way: double averages[NCOL];

Comment: When you say *not correct* does it mean not accurate or plain wrong ? Could it be an inversion of rows and columns ?

Comment: @Igor wouldn't that give the sum of row not the column. I want sum of column

Comment: @SergeBallesta by wrong I mean inaccurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not show that you initialize `averages` to `0` :

```
for(n = 0; n < NCOL; n++){
    averages[n] = 0.;
    for(m = 0; m < NROW; m++){
        averages[n] += twoD[n][m]; //averages is an array of type double
    }
}
```

Another problem for accuracy (but I do not think it is the case with double values) is that is is more accurate when computing the average of value with little variance to first gess an approximation of the average and then compute : `avg(X) = x1 + avg(X - x1)` where `x1` is the guess for `avg(X)`.

Comment: thank you. adding averages[n] = 0.; inside the outer and outside the inner loop did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

In the for loops the first `for` should take all the columns and the second `for` all the rows.
For example: **column=1** and then you go with the second `for` and get the values for all the rows on that column **row=1, row=2** and so on.

```
for(n = 0; n < NCOL; n++){ \\for each column
    for(m = 0; m < NROW; m++){ \\take each row of each column
        averages[n] += twoD[m][n]; //row m, column n
    }
}
```

Comment: I am still getting inaccurate answers. For example when it should return 21.63, it actually returns 21.14. 88.64 instead of 88.40 and so on